# JavaFX loadSkinClass Failed

Tags: java, javafx

I am new to JavaFX, so my question might be really basic. I am trying to create a simple window with a button but I am stuck with this error:

```
SEVERE: javafx.scene.control.Control loadSkinClass Failed to load skin 'StringProperty [bean: Button[id=null, styleClass=button], name: skinClassName, value: com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ButtonSkin]' for control Button[id=null, styleClass=button]
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.t2k.MacFontFinder.initPSFontNameToPathMap(MacFontFinder.java:339)
    at com.sun.t2k.MacFontFinder.getFontNamesOfFontFamily(MacFontFinder.java:390)
    at com.sun.t2k.T2KFontFactory.getFontResource(T2KFontFactory.java:232)
    at com.sun.t2k.LogicalFont.getSlot0Resource(LogicalFont.java:184)
    at com.sun.t2k.LogicalFont.getSlotResource(LogicalFont.java:228)
    at com.sun.t2k.CompositeStrike.getStrikeSlot(CompositeStrike.java:86)
    at com.sun.t2k.CompositeStrike.getMetrics(CompositeStrike.java:132)
    at com.sun.javafx.font.PrismFontUtils.getFontMetrics(PrismFontUtils.java:31)
    at com.sun.javafx.font.PrismFontLoader.getFontMetrics(PrismFontLoader.java:451)
    at javafx.scene.text.Text.<init>(Text.java:153)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.LabeledText.<init>(LabeledText.java:31)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.LabeledSkinBase.<init>(LabeledSkinBase.java:130)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ButtonSkin.<init>(ButtonSkin.java:45)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at javafx.scene.control.Control.loadSkinClass(Control.java:1044)
    at javafx.scene.control.Control.access$500(Control.java:70)
    at javafx.scene.control.Control$12.invalidated(Control.java:972)
    at javafx.beans.property.StringPropertyBase.markInvalid(StringPropertyBase.java:127)
    at javafx.beans.property.StringPropertyBase.set(StringPropertyBase.java:161)
    at com.sun.javafx.css.StyleableStringProperty.set(StyleableStringProperty.java:71)
    at javafx.scene.control.Control$12.set(Control.java:964)
    at com.sun.javafx.css.StyleableStringProperty.applyStyle(StyleableStringProperty.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.css.StyleableStringProperty.applyStyle(StyleableStringProperty.java:31)
    at com.sun.javafx.css.StyleableProperty.set(StyleableProperty.java:70)
    at com.sun.javafx.css.StyleHelper.transitionToState(StyleHelper.java:900)
    at javafx.scene.Node.impl_processCSS(Node.java:7419)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_processCSS(Parent.java:1146)
    at javafx.scene.control.Control.impl_processCSS(Control.java:1154)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_processCSS(Parent.java:1153)
    at javafx.scene.Node.processCSS(Node.java:7387)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.doCSSPass(Scene.java:454)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.preferredSize(Scene.java:1468)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_preferredSize(Scene.java:1535)
    at javafx.stage.Window$9.invalidated(Window.java:716)
    at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.markInvalid(BooleanPropertyBase.java:127)
    at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.set(BooleanPropertyBase.java:161)
    at javafx.stage.Window.setShowing(Window.java:779)
    at javafx.stage.Window.show(Window.java:794)
    at javafx.stage.Stage.show(Stage.java:230)
    at edu.troupmar.aop.hw_01.Applet.start(Applet.java:34)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$5.run(LauncherImpl.java:319)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$5.run(PlatformImpl.java:219)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4$1.run(PlatformImpl.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4$1.run(PlatformImpl.java:179)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4.run(PlatformImpl.java:179)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:76)

SEVERE: javafx.scene.control.Control impl_processCSS The -fx-skin property has not been defined in CSS for Button[id=null, styleClass=button]
SEVERE: javafx.scene.control.Control impl_processCSS The -fx-skin property has not been defined in CSS for Button[id=null, styleClass=button]
```

Here is my code:

```
public class Applet extends Application {

    Button button;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        stage.setTitle("Title of the Window");
        button = new Button();
        button.setText("Click me");

        StackPane layout = new StackPane();
        layout.getChildren().add(button);
        Scene scene = new Scene(layout, 300, 250);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

}
```

The window by itself appears but the button does not due to the error.

Thank your for any replay!

Comment: It seems to be a font problem. Try changing the default font or set the font of button to different one. It also can be installation problem, try with different version of JavaFX.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Changing jdk-7 to jdk-8 fixed it after all.

Comment: JavaFX 2.X works fine with Java 1.7, there seems to be an issue with using system font, I changed to Arial and it launched using java 1.7.0_76

Answer (score 0):

Updating JavaFX version from 2.1 to 2.2 helped me resolve this issue.